# C# Interpreted Language

Tags: c#, parsing, interpreted-language

I am looking to write an interpreted language in C#, where should I start? I know how I would do it using fun string parsing, but what is the correct way?

Answer (score 8):

It can be a pretty difficult endeavour to do right.

If you don't have much knowledge in compiler theory you should probably first start reading about it.
Just using "fun string parsing", if I understand that term correctly, isn't going to get you very far at all.

The first basic step is to write your language grammar that defines the valid syntax for the language.
A tool like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) will help you get the pieces together, but I would suggest reading the [Dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) as it is the canonical starting point to get up to speed on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to build an interpreted language on .NET, the DLR is the way to go - check out Martin Maly's LOLCODE sample at http://www.iunknown.com/2007/11/lolcode-on-dlr.html

Edit: Here's another link with more information from Scott Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode11LOLCodeDLREdition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Phoenix compiler](http://connect.microsoft.com/Phoenix) from Microsoft.   This will provide many of the tools you will need to build a compiler targeting native or managed environments.  Among these tools us a optimizing back end.

I second Cycnus' suggestion on reading Aho Sethi and Ullman's "Dragon Book" ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811)).

RGR